# Youtube API Boolean search result giving me wrong results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube.net-api

At https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

it says "To search for an exact phrase, enclose the phrase in quotation marks. For example, to search for videos matching the phrase "spy plane", set the q parameter to %22spy+plane%22."

But for example I want vids with "Hong Jason" in the title. But,

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=2&q=intitle:%22Hong+Jason%22&orderby=viewCount

I get "Mr. Curiosity by Jeffery Hong (Jason Mraz cover)"

It seems that vid was got because it has "Hong (Jason"

So Youtube can't eliminate that "(", so I got incorrect result.

How can I solve this?

How can I do a REAL exact search?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the documentation could use some update ?
Try this:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=intitle:%22Hong%22+%22Jason%22-%22Mraz%22&prettyprint=true&alt=json&max-results=3&order=relevance&fields=entry(title,link[@rel='alternate'])